# What's the difference between "generally" and "usually"?

Tags: difference

> I don't generally talk like that

> I don't usually talk like that

To me, a non native speaker, "generally" and "usually" sound the same. What's the difference between "generally" and "usually"?

Answer (score 2):

**Generally** and **usually** are synonyms when they refer to the frequency or likelihood of something happening under normal circumstances, or to what is common or unexceptional practice.

> We generally go to the beach during vacation.
>
> We usually go to the beach during vacation.

But **generally** can also refer to a class, especialy in terms of a common attribute, and we cannot use **usually** there.

> When she said people tend to exaggerate, she meant **people generally**. A tendency to exaggerate is a trait of people all over the world. It is a human trait. But maybe exaggeration varies from culture to culture?

Comment: Could you please explain with the example i gave?

Comment: Do you know what the word **syonym** means?

Comment: Yes but. Generally means in the general case. Where as usually means habitually.(most often). So how the hell they're synonyms?

Comment: Native speakers often use **generally** and **usually** interchangeably.  The general case is the most usually encountered case. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generally

Comment: If we see practically if something happens more often it is the most common case. So generally and usually mean the same thing. I got it what you wanted to say. lol

Comment: Somehow I think that _usually_ might a bit stronger than _generally_. If something happens about 60% of the time, I might be more inclined to use _generally_, whereas if it happens more like 90% of the time, I might be more inclined to use _usually_. But this is just a mere hunch on my part; I'm not aware of any such hard-and-fast guidelines about this matter.

Comment: I guess this is a verbal counterpart to the Sorites problem: when does the general become the usual?   *Bartender, make it the general.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be rude, but...

> > > Always look up the word roots! (aka 'the etymology') and

> > > Google is usually the least informative choice for looking up the meaning of a word!

Now, to answer your question, I have listed the definitions of the words 'general' and 'usual' at the bottom of the page. They were supplied through the courtesy of:

The Collaborative International Dictionary of English v.0.48

The term "general" is derived from the latin word from which we get 'genus'.
A genus can only be determined from "a system"
and systems, by definition, have rules.

So first, you can imply that - in this usage:

"generally" means "as a rule"

Therefore

"I don't generally talk like that" means:

I don't, as a rule, talk like that.

or - your personal, professional, or cultural rules do not require you to 'talk like that'.

Next:

"usually" refers to either frequency, or habit
hence "I don't usually talk like that"
can mean:

I don't frequently talk like that.

or

I don't, as a habit, talk like that.

(BTW: I think
'speak that way'
is a little better choice than
'talk like that'
Why? Probably because the word "that" is just kind of dangling off the end of the sentence, where 'speak' allows you to adjust 'that'-s position. Possibly improving the accuracy of understanding.
... something along those lines...)

> > > The secret to English is the Dictionary.

You can quote me on that!

Peace

Below are the actual definitions:

Also: note that when multiple definitions are given, the compilers attempt to list the most common usage first, followed by the next most common (or nex-most likely) meaning & etc.

General Gen"er*al, a. [F. g['e]n['e]ral, fr. L. generalis. See
Genus.]

1. Relating to a genus or kind; pertaining to a whole class
   or order; as, a general law of animal or vegetable
   economy.
   [1913 Webster]
2. Comprehending many species or individuals; not special or
   particular; including all particulars; as, a general
   inference or conclusion.
   [1913 Webster]
3. Not restrained or limited to a precise import; not
   specific; vague; indefinite; lax in signification; as, a
   loose and general expression.
   [1913 Webster]
4. Common to many, or the greatest number; widely spread;
   prevalent; extensive, though not universal; as, a general
   opinion; a general custom.
   [1913 Webster]
5. Having a relation to all; common to the whole; as, Adam,
   our general sire. --Milton.
   [1913 Webster]
6. As a whole; in gross; for the most part.
   [1913 Webster]
7. Usual; common, on most occasions; as, his general habit or
   method.
   [1913 Webster]

Note: The word general, annexed to a name of office, usually
denotes chief or superior; as, attorney-general;
adjutant general; commissary general; quartermaster
general; vicar-general, etc.
[1913 Webster]

---

Usual U"su*al, a. [L. usualis, from usus use: cf. F. usuel.
See Use, n.]

Such as is in common use; such as occurs in ordinary
practice, or in the ordinary course of events; customary;
ordinary; habitual; common.
[1913 Webster]

Comment: The OP didn't mention Google as a reference, so your mention is irrelevant.  As is half the rest of the post.

Comment: The etymological fallacy runs strong in this one.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Carney: Why do English dictionaries include the etymology?
Just curious.